# Adding a score in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Hi I want to add a score system in this Memory game, but i don't how to add it or how it update. I want it when the user finds two pairs that matches it will give you a score of 1 and if you find more pairs it will add 1 to the score.

This is my first time here so I don't if I should paste all the code, but here it is anyways
If you want to run it on python, you have to dedent all by 4

```
## MemoryPuzzle.py

import random, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*

FPS =           20 ## frames per second, the general speed of the game
WINDOWWIDTH =  640 ##size of height in pixels
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480 ##size of height in pixels
REVEALSPEED =    8 ## speed of boxes sliding reveals and covers
BOXSIZE=        40 ## Size of box, width and height in pixels
GAPSIZE =       10 ##spaces between the box
BOARDWIDTH =    10 ## number of columns of icons
BOARDHEIGHT =    7 ##  numbers of rows of icons
assert (BOARDWIDTH * BOARDHEIGHT) % 2==0, "Board needs to have an evem number of boxes for pairs to match."
XMARGIN = int((WINDOWWIDTH - (BOARDWIDTH * (BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE))) / 2)
YMARGIN = int((WINDOWHEIGHT - (BOARDHEIGHT * (BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE))) / 2)

#                           R        G       B
GRAY     =                (100,     100,    100)
NAVYBLUE =                ( 60,      60,    100)
WHITE    =                (125,     255,    255)
RED      =                (255,       0,      0)
GREEN    =                (  0,     255,      0)
BLUE     =                (  0,       0,    255)
YELLOW   =                (255,     255,      0)
ORANGE   =                (255,     128,      0)
PURPLE   =                (255,       0,    255)
CYAN     =                (  0,     255,    255)

BGCOLOR= NAVYBLUE
LIGHTBGCOLOR = GRAY
BOXCOLOR = WHITE
HIGHLIGHTCOLOR = BLUE

DONUT = "donut"
SQUARE = "square"
DIAMOND = "diomond"
LINES = "lines"
OVAL = "oval"

ALLCOLORS = (RED, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW, ORANGE, PURPLE, CYAN)
ALLSHAPES = (DONUT, SQUARE, DIAMOND, LINES, OVAL)
assert len(ALLCOLORS) * len(ALLSHAPES) * 2 >= BOARDWIDTH * BOARDHEIGHT, "Board is too big for the number of shapes/colors defined."

def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF =pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT)) 
    mousex = 0# used to store x cooridinate of mouse event
    mousey = 0# used to store y cooridinate of mouse event
    pygame.display.set_caption("MemoryGame")

    mainBoard = getRandomizedBoard()
    revealedBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)

    firstSelection = None #stores the (x, y) of the first box clicked

    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
    startGameAnimation(mainBoard)

    while True: #main game loop
        mouseClicked = False

        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        drawBoard(mainBoard, revealedBoxes)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
                mouseClicked = True    

        boxx, boxy = getBoxAtPixel(mousex, mousey)
        if boxx != None and boxy != None:
            ## the mouse is over a box
            if not revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy]:
                drawHighlightBox(boxx, boxy)
            if not revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] and mouseClicked:
                revealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(boxx, boxy)])
                revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True #set the box as revealed
                if firstSelection == None: #the current box was the first
                    firstSelection = (boxx, boxy)
                else: # the current box was the second box clicked
                    #checks if theres is a match between the two icons.
                    icon1shape, icon1color = getShapeAndColor(mainBoard, firstSelection[0], firstSelection[1])
                    icon2shape, icon2color = getShapeAndColor(mainBoard, boxx, boxy)
                    if icon1shape != icon2shape or icon1color != icon2color:
                        #Icons dont match. Re_cover up Both Selections.
                        pygame.time.wait(1000) #1000 milliseconds = 1sec
                        coverBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(firstSelection[0], firstSelection[1]), (boxx, boxy)])
                        revealedBoxes[firstSelection[0]][firstSelection[1]] = False
                        revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = False
                    elif hasWon(revealedBoxes): #check if all pairs found
                        gameWonAnimation(mainBoard)
                        pygame.time.wait(2000)

                        #reset the board
                        mainBoard = getRandomizedBoard()
                        revealedBoxea = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)

                        #Show the fully unrevealed board for a second.
                        drawBoard(mainBoard, revealedBoxes)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        pygame.time.wait(1000)

                        #replay the start game animation
                        startGameAnimation(mainBoard)
                    firstSelection = None # reset first selection variable

        #redraw the screen and wait a clock tick
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def generateRevealedBoxesData(val):
    revealedBoxes = []
    for i in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        revealedBoxes.append([val] * BOARDHEIGHT)
    return revealedBoxes

def getRandomizedBoard():
    # Get a list of every possible shape with every possible color
    icons =[]
    for color in ALLCOLORS:
        for shape in ALLSHAPES:
            icons.append( (shape, color) )

    random.shuffle(icons) #Randomize the order of the icons
    numIconsUsed = int (BOARDWIDTH * BOARDHEIGHT / 2) # Calculate how many icons needed
    icons = icons [:numIconsUsed] *2 #make 2 of each
    random.shuffle(icons)

    #create the board data structure, with randomly placed icons.
    board =[]

    for x in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        column = []
        for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            column.append(icons[0])
            del icons[0] #removes the icons as we assigned them
        board.append(column)
    return board

def splitIntoGroupsOf(groupSize, theList):
    # splits a list into a list of lists, where the inner lists have at
    # most groupsize number of items.
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(theList), groupSize):
        result.append(theList[i:i + groupSize])
    return result

def leftTopCoordsOfBox(boxx, boxy):
    #convert board cooridinates to pixel cooridinates
    left = boxx *(BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE) + XMARGIN
    top = boxy * (BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE) + YMARGIN
    return (left, top) 

def getBoxAtPixel(x, y):
    for boxx in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for boxy in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            left, top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(boxx, boxy)
            boxRect = pygame.Rect(left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE)
            if boxRect.collidepoint(x, y):
                return (boxx, boxy)
    return (None, None)

def drawIcon(shape, color, boxx, boxy):
    quarter = int(BOXSIZE * 0.25) #syntactic sugar
    half = int(BOXSIZE * 0.5)

    left, top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(boxx, boxy) #get pixel corrds from board coords
    #draw shapes
    if shape == DONUT:
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, color, (left + half, top + half), half - 5)
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, BGCOLOR, (left +half, top + half), quarter - 5)

    elif shape == SQUARE:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, color, (left + quarter, top + quarter, BOXSIZE - half, BOXSIZE -half))

    elif shape== DIAMOND:
        pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAYSURF, color, ((left + half, top), (left + BOXSIZE - 1, top + half), (left + half, top + BOXSIZE - 1), (left, top + half)))

    elif shape == LINES:
        for i in range(0, BOXSIZE, 4):
            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, color, (left, top+ i), (left + i, top))
            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, color, ( left + i, top + BOXSIZE - 1), (left + BOXSIZE -1, top + i ))

    elif shape == OVAL:
        pygame.draw.ellipse(DISPLAYSURF, color, (left, top + quarter, BOXSIZE, half))

def getShapeAndColor( board, boxx, boxy):
    #color value for x, y spot is stored in board[x] [y] [1]
    return board[boxx][boxy][0], board[boxx][boxy][1]

def drawBoxCovers(board, boxes, coverage):
    #draws boxes being covered/revealed. "boxes" is a list
    #of two item lists, which have the x & y "spot of the box.
    for box in boxes:
        left, top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(box[0], box[1])
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BGCOLOR, (left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE))
        shape, color = getShapeAndColor(board, box[0], box[1])
        drawIcon(shape, color, box[0], box[1])
        if coverage > 0: #only draw the cover if there is an coverage
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BOXCOLOR, (left, top, coverage, BOXSIZE))
    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def revealBoxesAnimation(board, boxesToReveal):
    #do the "box reveal" animation.
    for coverage in range(BOXSIZE, (-REVEALSPEED) -1, - REVEALSPEED):
        drawBoxCovers(board, boxesToReveal, coverage)

def coverBoxesAnimation(board, boxesToReveal):
    #Do the "box cover" animation
    for coverage in range(0, BOXSIZE + REVEALSPEED, REVEALSPEED):
        drawBoxCovers(board, boxesToReveal, coverage)

def drawBoard(board, revealed):
    for boxx in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for boxy in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            left, top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(boxx, boxy)
            if not revealed[boxx][boxy]:
                #Draw a covered box.
                pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BOXCOLOR, (left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE))
            else:
                #draw the (revealed) icon
                shape, color = getShapeAndColor(board, boxx, boxy)
                drawIcon(shape, color, boxx, boxy)

def drawHighlightBox(boxx, boxy):
    left, top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(boxx, boxy)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, HIGHLIGHTCOLOR, (left - 5, top - 5, BOXSIZE + 10, BOXSIZE + 10), 4)

def startGameAnimation(board):
    #Randomly reval boxes 8 at a time.
    coveredBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)
    boxes = []
    for x in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            boxes.append( (x, y) )
    random.shuffle(boxes)
    boxGroups = splitIntoGroupsOf(8, boxes)

    drawBoard(board, coveredBoxes)
    for boxGroup in boxGroups:
        revealBoxesAnimation(board, boxGroup)
        coverBoxesAnimation(board, boxGroup)

def gameWonAnimation(board):
    #flash the background color when teh player has won
    coveredBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(True)
    color1 = LIGHTBGCOLOR
    color2 = BGCOLOR

    for i in range (13):
        color1, color2= color2, color1 #swap colors
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(color1)
        drawBoard(board, coveredBoxes)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.wait(300)

def hasWon(revealedBoxes):
    #Return True if all the boxes have been revealed, otherwise False
    for i in revealedBoxes:
        if False in i:
            return False # return False if any boxes are covered
    return True

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, It's just add a `score = 0` variable outside the `while True` loop and keep manipulating the `score` inside this loop in these locations:

Here:

```
if firstSelection == None: #the current box was the first
    firstSelection = (boxx, boxy)
    score += 1
```

And here:

```
if icon1shape != icon2shape or icon1color != icon2color:
    #Icons dont match. Re_cover up Both Selections.
    pygame.time.wait(1000) #1000 milliseconds = 1sec
    coverBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(firstSelection[0], firstSelection[1]), (boxx, boxy)])
    revealedBoxes[firstSelection[0]][firstSelection[1]] = False
    revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = False
    score -= 1
```

Inside `hasWon()` you can reset the score.

I did in this way, trying to follow your logic of keeping the boxes revealed.

---

EDIT:

```
#create font obj outside loop
font_path = "./fonts/newfont.ttf"
font=pygame.font.Font(font_path, font_size)
#other option:
#font=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", font_size)
```

Inside the loop:

```
scoretext = font.render(str(score), 1,(255,255,255))
screen.blit(scoretext, (x, y))
```

Not a good solution, but works...